# Magento 2 : How to add additional field in Email Template?

Tags: magento2, email-templates, order-email

I have created my custom Payment Method in Magento2 and also 2 fields in Payment method now everything working fine now I want send the 2 additional field data in sales order email so how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/order_new.html` template in your theme or module to add your variable output.

and use the event `email_order_set_template_vars_before` to add your variables to the template